# Mudar variável e salvá-la pelo AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

Estou desenvolvendo um APP que contém diversos textos, por isso o tamanho da fonte dos textos são importados de uma única variável.
Estou tentando adicionar uma opção para deixar a fonte maior, e salvar o tamanho da fonte escolhida, mas, não estou conseguindo.

Segue o código que **altera** e **salva** a variável `tamanhoFonte`.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    Button,
    AsyncStorage,
    View
} from 'react-native';

//Variável que é exportada para todos os textos
export var tamanhoFonte = 18;

export var corTexto = `#646567`;

export var nightMode = false;

export default class Variaveis extends Component {


    _storeData() {      
        AsyncStorage.setItem('tamanhoFonte',tamanhoFonte) 
    }

    _retrieveData() {
       AsyncStorage.getItem('tamanhoFonte')
       this.setState({tamanhoFonte:tamanhoFonte})    

    }

    componentWillMount() {
       this._retrieveData();
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { tamanhoFonte: tamanhoFonte }
    }

    mudaFonte = () => {
        this.setState({tamanhoFonte: this.state.tamanhoFonte+1})
        this._storeData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.state.tamanhoFonte} </Text>
                <Button title="Muda fonte" onPress={() => { this.mudaFonte() }} />
            </View>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na função _retrieveData o getItem do AsyncStorage não é atribuído a nenhuma variável. Tem esse exemplo: https://medium.com/@richardzhanguw/storing-and-retrieving-objects-using-asyncstorage-in-react-native-6bb1745fdcdd